# ajax is not able to call the function of codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

```
This is Welcome controller method 

    public function send_otp()
    {
        echo 'in';
      die;
        $phone = $_POST['mobile'];
        if ($phone != '') {
            $mobile_detail = $this->welcome_model->check_if_already_mobile_no($phone);
            if (!empty($mobile_detail)) {
                if ($mobile_detail['is_verified'] == 'yes') {
                    $message = 'Already Verified.';
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $message));
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $this->welcome_model->delete_mobile_no($phone);
                }
            }

            $otp = self::generateRandomNo();
            $this->welcome_model->insert_mobile_detail($phone, $otp);
            $link = file_get_contents("http://49.50.67.32/smsapi/httpapi.jsp?username=aplusv&password=aplusv1&from=APLUSV&to=$phone&text=$otp&coding=0");
            $status = '';
            if ($link != '') {
                $status = 'success';
                $message = 'Successfully Otp send to your no.';
            } else {
                $status = 'error';
                $message = 'Error in sending OTP.';
            }
            echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'message' => $message));
            exit;
        }
    }
This is model 
 public function check_if_already_mobile_no($mobile_no = null)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('mobile_sms', array('mobile_no' => $mobile_no));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function get_mobile_details($mobile_no = null, $otp = null)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('mobile_sms', array('mobile_no' => $mobile_no, 'otp' => $otp));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function insert_mobile_detail($phone, $otp)
    {
        $this->mobile_no = $phone;
        $this->otp = $otp;
        $this->is_verified = 'no';
        $this->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $this->db->insert('mobile_sms', $this);
    }
This is view 
     <div class="container" style="margin-top: 25px;">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="response_msg"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="enter_mobile">
                    <form method="POST" action="#">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Phone </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Mobile">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" name="send_mobile" id="send_otp" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
   // var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () { // start of doc ready.
                $("#send_otp").on('click', function (e) {
                    var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
                    alert(mobile);

                    $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url('index.php/welcome/send_otp'); ?>', 
                        data: {'mobile': mobile}, 
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.status == 'success') {
                                $('#response_msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">' + data.message + '</div>');
                                $('#mobile_no').val(mobile);
                                $('#enter_mobile').hide();
                                $('#verify_otp_form').show();
                            } else {
                                $('#response_msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + data.message + '</div>');
                            }
                        }
                    });

                });
```

in ajax is not getting call ie $.ajax is not working here and my controller ie welcome with method send_otp is not called here.
why my function in controller is not getting called 
how to solve the issue
what is the proper way to call the controller function using base_url 
i have check the console also it is not showing any error

Comment: are getting mobile alert?

Comment: @M.Hemant yes  getting mobile alert

Answer (score 0):

1. I noticed that you are using [site_url()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url) slightly incorrectly: don't write index.php there, just use `site_url('welcome/send_otp')`
2. Don't forget you have an unconditional `die()` at the top of your `send_otp`  method - it will prevent any code below itself from executing

Comment: @badwe  i have followed both the two point but now in controller function it should echo me echo 'in'; but it is not

Comment: which http status code do you get when you go directly in your browser to http://your-site.url/index.php/welcome/send_otp ?

Comment: @badwe i m getting 200 status but the page i m getting 404 page not found

Comment: you can't get a 200 and a 404

Comment: This is clearly a routing issue. Try to set `log_threshold` to `4` (all messages) in application/config/config.php and check application/logs for which controller and function get called. Then edit routes.php and/or .htaccess accordingly